¿Como configurar variables de ambiente en un proyecto React con Vite y desplegando con Vercel?
He hecho un proyecto sencillo usando la API de TMDB en React con Vite. Ya lo tengo en su repositorio. Tengo un archivo .env.local donde he creado una variable de ambiente para la API KEY de esta manera:
VITE_API_KEY=xxxxx
En el codigo accedo a esta clave unicamente desde un hook custom asi:

En el local todo funciona perfecto el problema es que al desplegar con Vercel y configurar las variables de ambiente en el proyecto, no termina de funcionar la app me da el error de que la api key es incorrecta osea no la está detectando
Aqui ya configure Vercel en el proyecto para usar la variable de ambiente.


No conozco la interfaz de Vercel por lo que puedo estar equivocado, pero quería señalar que en la imagen se puede ver que dice API_KEY. Entiendo que debería ser VITE_API_KEY, no?

@Marcos ya lo edite Vercel me marca que si le coloco el prefijo VITE se expone los datos al navegador

Proba cambiar el nombre de la variable en el código. PD: Por lo que se puede ver en la documentación de Vercel > Variables de entorno, la forma correcta de obtener el valor es, por ejemplo,process.env.API_URL;. Repito, no conozco la plataforma. Saludos!

No hay cambios lo escribi asi: process.env.API_KEY y no lo toma tampoco

Hice el cambio en Vercel y llame a la variable VITE_API_KEY para que sea igual que en el codigo pero persiste el problema
